# Delegate methods and User Controls c#

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, user-controls

Hi this is my first post here, apologies for bad english.

I have many classes that have a single method that have to be redefined runtime.
The following code runs fine:

```
public interface Interface1
{
    Action MyCustomAction { get; set; }
}

public class Class1 : Interface1
{
    private Action _myCustomAction;
    public Action MyCustomAction {  get => _myCustomAction==null?delegate() { }:_myCustomAction; set => _myCustomAction = value; }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        //do a lot of stuff, then call:
        MyCustomAction();
    }
}
```

Good, i can do this:

```
 Class1 c1 = new Class1();
 c1.MyCustomAction = delegate () { Console.WriteLine("I successfully redefined the custom action inside a " + c1.ToString()); };
 c1.DoStuff();
```

and be happy.

But now comes the problem, check the following:

```
public interface Interface1
{
    Action MyCustomAction { get; set; }
}

public partial class Class1: UserControl, Interface1
{
    private Action _myCustomAction ;
    public Action MyCustomAction { get => _myCustomAction == null ? delegate () { }: _myCustomAction; set => _myCustomAction = value; }

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void DoStuff() {
        //do a lot of stuff, then call:
        MyCustomAction();
    }
}
```

Apparently same thing except for Class1 is a UserControl
And now, when i drag and drop a Class1 User control from the Toolbar into the main form... bang! Error appear in Visual studio 2017..

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Invalid Resx file. Could not load type WindowsFormsApp2.UserControl1+<>c, WindowsFormsApp2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null which is used in the .RESX file.  Ensure that the necessary references have been added to your project. Line 142, position 5. WindowsFormsApp2    C:\Users\tara\source\repos\WindowsFormsApp2\WindowsFormsApp2\Form1.resx 142

and in the main form resx now appear a lot of strange code like this

```
  <data name="userControl11.MyCustomAction" mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.binary.base64">
<value>
    AAEAAAD/////AQAAAAAAAAAMAgAAAEdXaW5kb3dzRm9ybXNBcHAyLCBWZXJzaW9uPTEuMC4wLjAsIEN1
    bHR1cmU9bmV1dHJhbCwgUHVibGljS2V5VG9rZW49bnVsbAQBAAAAIlN5c3RlbS5EZWxlZ2F0ZVNlcmlh
    bGl6YXRpb25Ib2xkZXIDAAAACERlbGVnYXRlB3RhcmdldDAHbWV0aG9kMAMEAzBTeXN0ZW0uRGVsZWdh
    dGVTZXJpYWxpemF0aW9uSG9sZGVyK0RlbGVnYXRlRW50cnkhV2luZG93c0Zvcm1zQXBwMi5Vc2VyQ29u
    dHJvbDErPD5jAgAAAC9TeXN0ZW0uUmVmbGVjdGlvbi5NZW1iZXJJbmZvU2VyaWFsaXphdGlvbkhvbGRl
    cgkDAAAACQQAAAAJBQAAAAQDAAAAMFN5c3RlbS5EZWxlZ2F0ZVNlcmlhbGl6YXRpb25Ib2xkZXIrRGVs
    ZWdhdGVFbnRyeQcAAAAEdHlwZQhhc3NlbWJseQZ0YXJnZXQSdGFyZ2V0VHlwZUFzc2VtYmx5DnRhcmdl
    dFR5cGVOYW1lCm1ldGhvZE5hbWUNZGVsZWdhdGVFbnRyeQEBAgEBAQMwU3lzdGVtLkRlbGVnYXRlU2Vy
    aWFsaXphdGlvbkhvbGRlcitEZWxlZ2F0ZUVudHJ5BgYAAAANU3lzdGVtLkFjdGlvbgYHAAAAS21zY29y
```

I remove the user control form the form and the error disappear
I add the user control, and it appears again.
I am very confused, i have no  idea why this happens... and how to fix

Comment: This happened because the property is public, has both and getter and setter and has a non-null value at design-time.  You have to give it an attribute to prevent the value from getting saved to the .resx file, apply [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)].  Or fix the getter, no point in using an anonymous method.  Null is fine, you are probably hiding another bug somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add this attribute to your property:

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
```

This tells the WinForms designer that the property should not be saved into the code generated file.

MSDN:

> Specifies the visibility a property has to the design-time serializer
>
> The code generator does not produce code for the object

Additionally you may want to add `[Browsable(false)]` so that it is not visible at all in the designer.  It might not affect code generation but there's arguably no point showing a property whose type can't be changed (`delegate/Action`).

So:

```
[Browsable(false)]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)] 
public Action MyCustomAction 
{ 
    get => _myCustomAction == null ? delegate () { }: _myCustomAction; 
    set => _myCustomAction = value; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.. your fix work fine!
I was unaware that my public properties on a UserControl class was exposed to the designer then serialized by it. 
I am wandering why the designer is unable to serialize a delegate () {...}  but is perfectly fine with all other properties. What's wrong with a delegate property? Just curious.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: @TaraRulez Probably something to do that there is no editor for it.  WinForms allows you to define your own editors for the property window. Not sure how one would do a delegate though